# z-index not working properly

Tags: html, css, z-index

So I am making a site and I have a top bar with some box shadow. I then have a description box directly underneath. So I set the z-indexes to ensure that the top bars box-shadow would go over the description box with the following css:

```
#topbar{
    z-index:9999 !important;
}
#description{
    margin-top:0px;
    z-index:-1 !important;
}
```

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BAW23/1/)

you will notice if you change the `margin-top`, you can see that the shadow is being hidden underneath the description still!

**why is this happening and how can I fix it?**

note: neither element can have fixed or absolute positioning

Comment: Usage of `!important` is almost always unnecessary. In this case you don't need it, just add `position:relative` to the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to both elements.  `z-index` only affects positioned elements.

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BAW23/3/